# redirect a POST to GET request

Tags: python, flask, redirect

I'm trying to understand what is the best way a POST request can be redirected to a GET request.
for example -

```
POST /redirect HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example1.com

url=www.example2.com
```

and i've created the following flask to help me with that :

```
from flask import Flask,request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/redirect',methods=['POST'])
def redire():
    url = request.form['url']
    return redirect('https://www.example2.com', code=307)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8888)
```

the "issue" in my case, is that the request that is being sent to

```
https://www.example2.com
```

is also a POST request which is not what i wanted.

Consider that I don't "care" about the body that needs to be sent to the

```
https://www.example2.com
```

endpoint, what is the best way to do so without any user intervention (meaning that I'm aiming for an auto redirect).

Note: I've tried to do it via PHP but I can't seem to figure it out.

Apologies if something is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

In order to redirect a POST request to a GET request, you need to use `code=303` because it requires the client to use the GET method to retrieve the requested resource.

```
@app.route('/redirect',methods=['POST'])
def redire():
    url = request.form['url']
    return redirect('https://www.example2.com', code=303)
```

Comment: can i add a custom header in the redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

the server

```
from flask import Flask, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/redirect', methods=['POST'])
def redire():
    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8888/get')


@app.route('/get', methods=['GET'])
def iam_get():
    return {"code": "ok"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8888)
```

the client

```
import requests


data = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8888/get")
print(data.text)

data = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8888/redirect")
print(data.text)
```

the result as follows

```
{"code":"ok"}

{"code":"ok"}
```

Comment: that's ok, but still, the request that is being sent to /get is a POST request.

Comment: Only get requests can be generated, when using  flask.redirect.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more ? (: